# Display a div within view port

Tags: javascript, css

I've an image gallery, that displays images in a 5X5 matrix. Each image has a `onmouseover` function where in a hidden div is displayed with some details about the image and the div with the details gets hidden using `onmouseout`. The div that contains the details about the image may contain clickable links and hence I am displaying the div just under the cursor position.

The problem I am facing is with the images in the 5th column. If the div that contains the details has more content, it creates a horizontal scroll bar and the details get cut off. 
How do I always show the details div inside the view port just under the cursor?

There's not much to it but here's the code

```
function eventRollOver(id) {

    var did = 'img_'+id;
    document.getElementById(did).style.display='';
}
function eventRollOut(id) {
    var did = 'img_'+id;
    document.getElementById(did).style.display='none';
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`overflow:hidden`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html)

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use CSS absolute positioning for the details div `position:absolute`, and also extract the mouse location from the event object ( [how-to](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position) )  in order to apply the x and y values of the mouse to the left and top CSS properties of the div..